# Standalone ATmega328p not working

Tags: microcontroller, arduino, pcb-design, atmega328p

I designed a standalone ATmega328p board (like an Arduino Nano).
I use an Arduino Nano as an ISP Programmer, I can set the fuse bits and flash the program to it.
But the ATmega shows absolutely no signs of life (I built an LED with resistor on pin PB2 and wanted it to make blink).

Tried another pin - not working. No signs of life at all.
All the parts except the ISP connector were soldered by the JLCBPCB SMT service.

Here is the schematic:

[image]

And here are the pictures of the PCB design:

Top Layer:

[image]

Bottom Layer:

[image]

Did I make a design error which I'm not seeing or is the chip maybe just broken?

I let JLC assemble two boards and they both behave the same - setting fuse bits and flashing the program - possible.
But blinking an LED - No. Absolutely no signs of life.

I personally doubt it, that BOTH chips are broken - as they are brand new.

Has anyone encountered a similar problem?
Thanks for your help.

Comment: Well, we don't know what components you used. Which 16 MHz device that is, a crystal or ceramic resonator? In which way you programmed the fuse bits? Have you determined that the LED is simply not mounted correctly but your program runs correctly? We also don't see what program you wrote, maybe there is a bug. Maybe the problem is just the missing bypass capacitors for supply, but it might not even program correctly if that would be the problem.

Comment: Are you sure you are not programming the Arduino Nano? What toolchain are you using for programming?

Comment: Is there more than what is shown in the schematics?

Comment: 1) I am using this crystal oscillator: https://www.lcsc.com/product-detail/Ceramic-Resonators_Murata-Electronics-CSTCE16M0V53-R0_C32180.html
I used it in another project before and the ATmega328p there worked without problems.

2) I am programming the ATmega328p and set the Arduino Nano as the ISP programmer.

3) No, there's no more than shown in the schematics. 

I'll try to mount an 100nF cap between VCC and GND and tell the result later.

Comment: Edit: added a 100nF cap between VCC and GND. No difference. 
Microcontroller broken?

Comment: When you upload a program, do you get errors? I mean, you wrote that it worked, but can you upload a second time w/o errors?

Comment: Yes, technically I can upload without errors. But sometimes my Arduino IDE says it cannot find the programmer (Arduino Nano) - I unplug the Arduino from USB, insert it again and then it works.

Comment: If you can upload the program, without errors, chances are that the uC is ok and the crystal is working (because uC is able to talk to the computer and confirm that it received the code). There can be an error in your code (which is easier to solve than a hardware problem). I suggest to get a simple code from the internet to continuously make blink all digital and analog outputs; compile and burn it; power the uC and probe each output pin with a led attached to a resistor. The continuity of the LED + resistor section can be tested, too (use a high resistor, don't fry PB2).

Comment: I used the simplest blink sketch - set the PB2 pin as an output, pulled the pin high, waited for 1000ms, pulled the pin low and waited for another 1000ms. I have a simple red LED with 220 Ohms current limiting resistor and it does not blink...

Answer (score 0):

Okay guys, finally found the solution for my problem:

At first I thought the capacitor C1 which is connected between RST and GND, was the problem, so I removed it. But this did not fix the problem.

It was indeed a software problem. I programmed the Mega328P using the Arduino IDE and [MiniCore](https://github.com/MCUdude/MiniCore).

It seems like for some reason, the standard Arduino commands "pinMode()", or "digitalWrite()" etc. don't work.

But when I'm using the port register commands with DDRx and PORTx, everything works.

So instead of writing

```
pinMode(PB2, OUTPUT);
digitalWrite(PB2, HIGH);
delay(1000);
digitalWrite(PB2, LOW);
delay(1000);
```

I wrote

```
DDRB |= (1<<PB2);
PORTB |= (1<<PB2);
delay(1000);
PORTB &= ~(1<<PB2);
delay(1000);
```

and that solved my problem.

Why didn't I think of that earlier?

Edit: what also works, is instead of

```
digitalWrite(PB2, HIGH);
```

writing

```
digitalWrite(PIN_PB2, HIGH);
```

Comment: You did not show any code. You simply said you are controlling pin PB2 and that was not true, but we had no reason to doubt that. For the pin which is PB2, PB2 is simply a define for number "2", and pin PB2 is not 2 for the Arduino functions. Pin PB2 is "digital pin 10". And it's a bit useless to post a rhetorical question why you did not think about that earlier. We don't have an answer for that.

Comment: We don't know what is hiding under the PIN_PB2 macro. This is not a standard AVR macro. You need to check it yourself.